# What is the alternative of an algebraic direct sum?

Tags: representation-theory

I'm working through some Lie theoretic representation theory, and the definition of a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module states that the representation $V$ decomposes into an algebraic direct sum of finite-dimensional invariant subspaces under the action of $K$. My question is, what other types of direct sum should I be concerned about here? Why specify *algebraic* direct sum?

Comment: It means as opposed to e.g. a Hilbert space or Banach space direct sum.